# Jquery body click stops toggle Button in AdminLTE

Tags: jquery, css, adminlte

I'm trying to use the toggle button to open and close the sidebarand in the same time when the sidebar is open i want it to close if we click on the body. The issue is when i click on body to close the sidebar, it's works well actually but the toggle button seems do not work at all (i mean only the close event for the toggle button). below my code :

```
$.AdminLTE.pushMenu = {
    activate: function (toggleBtn) {
      //Get the screen sizes
      var screenSizes = $.AdminLTE.options.screenSizes;

      //Enable sidebar toggle
      $(document).on('click', toggleBtn, function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //Handle sidebar push menu for small screens

          if ($("body").hasClass('sidebar-open')) {
            $("body").removeClass('sidebar-open');
          } else {
            $("body").addClass('sidebar-open');
          }

      });
    }
  };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Click event on body hide the element
        $("body").click(function() {
          if ($(window).width() < (991) && $("body").hasClass("sidebar-open")) {
            $("body").removeClass('sidebar-open');

          }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thans in advance for your helop !!

Comment: Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to do is remove the class sidebar-open and add collapse the sidebar-body.

```
$("body").removeClass('sidebar-open');
$("body").addClass('sidebar-collapse');
```